# Proof by induction: Is there an example of where statement $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ is true but you can never find a base case?

Tags: logic, induction

Is there an example of where one can show implication $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ holds true but the statement $P(n)$ was wrong so you can't find any case where $P(n)$ holds true? In other words, is it possible to get a true implication $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ from a wrong statement $P(n)$? If not why so? Because I know in truth table, $P \to Q$ can be true with $P$ being false since false statement can still lead to a true implication (ex: If $P$ is a false statement $-1 = 1$ then it implies statement $Q$: $(-1)^2=(1)^2$ which is a true statement.). I'm concerned about this because if you can show that the implication $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ is true but if you cannot find the base case, you don't know if your statement $P(n)$ was correct or not. Meaning there is proof by induction seems useless in such case. What am I missing in my understanding here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In here you have a case that the statement $p(n)$ implies $p(n+1)$ for all $n>1$, and $p(1)$ is true, but $p(2)$ is false so the whole argument collapse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: How about $P(n)$ is the statement “there are infinitely many primes less than $n$”. This is always false but there is an easy argument showing $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$. So yes, without the base case induction wont tell you anything.

Comment: Let $P(n)$ be $n\neq n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivial source of examples: if $\sum_{k=0}^na_k=b_n$ for all $n\ge0$, $\sum_{k=0}^na_k=b_n+c$ meets your requirement for any constant $c\ne0$.

What you're missing is that we really do need the base case. The principle of induction says if two things are true (base case & inductive step) the result follows.

Comment: So is there no such statement where base case is true and P(n)->P(n+1) is also true but it doesn't hold for some k (k not equal to base case)? What I'm worried about is a situation like this: let's say you are trying to write a formula for some pattern. You come up with a formula P(n) that seems to work for cases that you plug in (P(1), P(2), P(3)... etc) but let's say P(n) was actually wrong. Then it might be possible to show that P(n) implies P(n+1) is true since P(n) was a false statement. Then you proved a wrong statement and you are believing the formula works. I'm really bothered by this

Comment: @Mardia If $P(0)$, and if $P(n)\to P(n+1)$ for all $n\ge0$, then $P(n)$ for all $n\ge0$ (the quantification is over integers). The only thing you need to be careful of is checking the assumptions. For example, the famous "all horses are the same colour" joke is a case where, if $P(n)$ means $n+1$ horses are the same colour, $P(n)\to P(n+1)$ fails when $n=0$.

Comment: So for the "All horses are the same color" if I understand correctly, the implication P(n)->P(n+1) is true if P(n) is "n horses are same color" (Because P(n) is a false statement). You said the n = 0 fails but if n=2 holds, then we can show that our statement P(n) is true for all n>=2 by strong induction. Am I correct? What I'm worried is that if there is a false mathematical formula where true base case exists and P(n)->P(n+1) is also true thus which tells us P(n) holds for all n>= true base case. But now we believe our formula is correct when it was false in the first place.

Comment: @Mardia I said $P(n)$ meant $n+1$ horses (because my definition of induction starts at $n=0$. The point is $1$ horse ($n=0$) is fine, and going from e.g. $2$ horses to $3$ (the $n=1$ inductive step) is also fine, and yet because the $n=0$ inductive step fails later inductive steps are irrelevant. (If you think of induction as dominos knocking over dominos, it's as if the first knock-over step fails, so the later ones aren't even initiated.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking too much. I appreciate your effort. In here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color is it not stating that P(n) = n horses are same color? And it's possible to show P(n) -> P(n+1). The explanation says this is wrong because it assumes that group of horses are at least of size 3 and it fails when you only have 2 horses. But we can only consider the case where group of horses greater than 3. So a stronger induction says if there are group of horses of n>=3, then all horses in that group are same colored.

Comment: I'm thinking that this paradox occurs from assuming the false statement P(n) = "n horses are same color" is true. In this P(n) we can tell that it's intuitively wrong, but I think the problem occurs when we are dealing with more complex equation. If P(n) is an equation and it's false so we have no way to tell it's false. But since it's a false statement, if it's possible to show that there exists a base case and implication is true, then we will never know if this equation P(n) was true or not.

Comment: @Mardia All you can do is make sure the two parts of the inductive proof are indeed correct. A very careful analysis of the "horses" inductive step identifies when it fails. That's basically the point of the joke, to see if you can spot it. (The step relies on an intersection of two sets being nonempty.)

Comment: I think I understand that it the implication relies on intersection of two sets has to be nonempty in order for this to make sense. But then this statement P(n) is always true when two sets are always nonempty, am I correct? Is P(n) of "n horses are same color" not considered a false statement? (It's telling me that this commenting sections getting too long so I will just ask the question in another way on the forum. I will appreciate if you still answer to this comment though!).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134961/discussion-between-j-g-and-mardia).

Answer (score 2):

You need any statement that is always false.  Remember, false implies anything is true.    For instance:

$p(n):n=-1$ is false for all natural numbers, but would pass the inductive step.